# how to check mousemotion in an undefined direction in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to check if the mouse has moved following an undefined direction like so:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
        "do something"
```

then I want to print the direction. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility would be `pygame.mouse.get_rel()` which provides the amount of movement of the mouse since the last call to this function. This way you can avoid storing the previous position.

Simple example:

```
import sys, pygame,time

FPS=30
fpsClock=pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((650,650))
screen.fill(255,255,255)
done = False 

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            print pygame.mouse.get_rel()

    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

You will get an output like the one shown below and, as you can see, you can interpret it as vectors in the form *(x,y)* describing the direction of the movement:

```
(0, 0)
(-1, 0) 
(0, -8)
(0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are halfway there:

An event with type `pygame.MOUSEMOTION` event has a pos member.
You can store the previous pos, and calculate the difference - direction.